# Picasso: How to check if singleton is already set

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, picasso

I am using `Picasso` for handling image loading in my app. In my `Activity` I do

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.loading_screen);
    setupPicasso();
    // ...
}

private void setupPicasso()
{
    Cache diskCache = new Cache(getDir(CacheConstants.DISK_CACHE_DIRECTORY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE), CacheConstants.DISK_CACHE_SIZE);
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    okHttpClient.setCache(diskCache);

    Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(this)
            .memoryCache(new LruCache(CacheConstants.MEMORY_CACHE_SIZE))
            .downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(okHttpClient))
            .build();

    picasso.setIndicatorsEnabled(true); // For debugging

    Picasso.setSingletonInstance(picasso);
}
```

This works fine when first starting the app and when pausing the app by pressing the home button. However, when closing the app  by pressing the back button, followed by reopening the app, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Singleton instance already exists.
```

This happens because `Picasso` does not allow resetting the global singleton instance. What is the best way to work around this? Is it possible to check if the singleton is already set? Or do I need to keep a member variable in my `Activity` and check if that is `null`? Any best practice on this is appreciated.

Comment: If you really want to replace the shared instance, you can set it to null, and then reset it to your new instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call your `setupPicasso()` method from `onCreate` in your own `Application` 
class. Extend the [`Application`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class and override `onCreate`.  Then you will need to add the `name` attribute to your manifest's `<application>` section with the fully qualified application class.

```
package my.package

public class MyApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    setupPicasso();
}
```

Then in your manifest,

```
<application 
  android:name="my.package.MyApplication"
... >
```

Comment: This does not work since the application class can be called multiple times by the Android OS resulting in the IllegalStateException being thrown since the singleton instance will be already set when the application class is called a subsequent time.

Comment: Doing like this, it throws IllegalStateException while testing with robolectric as said @SavageKing. Using [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34834505/1797950) it works properly

Answer (score 1):

You will have to extend the application class like iagreen mentioned but you should also surround the setUpPicasso method with a try/catch so that if the exception is thrown you can handle it and prevent your application from crashing.

so

```
package my.package

public class MyApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() 
{
    super.onCreate();

    try
    {
        setupPicasso();
    }

    catch ( IllegalStateException e )
    {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

Comment: Might as well throw it in the Activity.onCreate at that point.

Comment: I was looking to solve the issue while testing with robolectric, It almost an evident solution, but did not think on it, lol. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this.

```
private static boolean initializedPicasso = false;


if (!initializedPicasso) {
     setupPicasso();
     initializedPicasso = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Surround the `setupPicasso()` method in a `try-catch` like so:

```
try
{
    setupPicasso();
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```