# Picasso is not working in android 10. Why?

Tags: java, android, picasso

I am trying to fetch an image from the URL by Picasso by a simple application. My `MainActivity.java` file is

```
'import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView iv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);

    Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load("https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/advertise.png").into(iv);
    }
}`
```

I Have Added Dependency For Picasso that is in build gradle which is :

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Here is my `manifest.xml` File :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.firebaseproject">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

After all of this, When I am trying to fetch this image from the URL, it is not showing anything in the app. Here Is the Screenshot of that
[image]

I am stuck in here for two days but can't find any solution after all overflow and youtube and google searches. Please help me if anyone knows how to fix this.

I am using android 10 OS in my Nokia 5.1 plus.
Any Suggestions Will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Start by checking the logcat to see if there is any error or output message that will help you. If not start adding `Log.d()` calls to determine where the problem is. Or use the Android Studio debugger to trace what is happening in your app.

Comment: Troubleshoot by different ways like @Code-Apprentice said. You can check on the network connection or by going back to the previous Picasso version .

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will do the same.@Code-Apprentice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find below code to print exception while fetching image through `Picasso`.
I have used the same version of this library that you have shared. I have tested this code into Realme 10 OS and Samsung 10. Its working.

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

In Java,

```
Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(this);
    builder.listener(new Picasso.Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    builder.build().load("https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/advertise.png").into(imageView);
```

In kotlin,

```
val builder = Picasso.Builder(this)
        builder.listener(fun(picasso: Picasso, uri: Uri, exception: Exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace()
        })
        builder.build().load("https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/advertise.png").into(imageView)
```

[image: Show image through Picasso]

Comment: One More Thing, I want to ask. What if I want to use this globally then how can I able to do this? Thanks In advance

Comment: Hey, check out this link for set up Picasso in application level. May be this help full for you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32288546/picasso-how-to-check-if-singleton-is-already-set

Answer (score 0):

Sheetal answer is right to find out the issue. Google has a new feature on **Android Q**:  filtered view for external storage. A quick fix for that is to add this code in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<manifest ... >
    <!-- This attribute is "false" by default on apps targeting Android Q. -->
    <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
     ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

You can read more about it  here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/compatibility